# Can't import scipy

Tags: scipy, python-3.7

My issue is about the import of scipy

#### Reproducing code example:

```
import scipy
```

#### Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Projects/gait/tests/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    import scipy
  File "C:\Users\Leynier\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 110, in <module>
    from scipy._lib._version import NumpyVersion as _NumpyVersion
  File "C:\Users\Leynier\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from scipy._lib._testutils import PytestTester
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Process finished with exit code 1
```

#### Scipy/Numpy/Python version information:

> - Scipy version: `1.3.0`
> - Numpy version: `1.16.4`
> - Python version: `3.7.3`
> - OS: `Windows 10`

Comment: are you using VS?

Comment: @Masoud I use the PyCharm, the Visual Studio code and the console. And in all variants the error is the same.

Comment: With Python version 3.6.8, this problem does not happen to me.